# ckeditor property to resize a image

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery, ckeditor

Is there any property in ckeditor that will resize the image after uploading to a specified dimension. for eg: if user uploads a image of `1000*1000 px` and doesn't resize it, it can be a massacre. As i am saving and displaying on the same page without refresh using ajax.
All i want is to automatically resize image on upload from ckeditor.
As well, is there any way that i can find using jquery whether there is any image in the text saved by user, as a user may or may not upload a image, I am using inplace ckeditor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CKFinder](http://ckfinder.com/) is an excellent companion to CKEditor, and allows one to set the maximum size of an uploaded image in its [configuration](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/PHP/Configuration/Images).

If you don't want to use that, you resize the image yourself in PHP with something like this:

```
<?php
$maxWidth  = 250;
$maxHeight = 500;

$size = getimagesize($url);
if ($size) {
    $imageWidth  = $size[0];
    $imageHeight = $size[1];
    $wRatio = $imageWidth / $maxWidth;
    $hRatio = $imageHeight / $maxHeight;
    $maxRatio = max($wRatio, $hRatio);
    if ($maxRatio > 1) {
        $outputWidth = $imageWidth / $maxRatio;
        $outputHeight = $imageHeight / $maxRatio;
    } else {
        $outputWidth = $imageWidth;
        $outputHeight = $imageHeight;
    }
}
?>
```

From: [Arbitrary image resizing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461167/arbitrary-image-resizing-in-php./461208#461208)

Comment: Is there any other way rather then using CkFinder, because we are already using ckeditor's uploader.

Comment: @user795419: if you're using CKEditor's uploader, then you must have access to the upload script?

Comment: Yes, I am already resizing it using PHP script but i need to resize it at the runtime as well, because the whole thing is working with ajax, as in inplace editor, the text is immediately displayed whatever is given
http://www.bitsntuts.com/demos/ckeip/ , try uploading a huge image, you will come to know, what i am talking about.

Comment: @user795419: So just use the same code to resize it within the server-size portion of your AJAX call