# How to fix image width in ckeditor while uploading the image?

Tags: php, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor on my site. while uploading the image form local system to server, I want to fix width  and height of  uploded image.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to solve it:

**1.** Create custom uploading script, which will "upload" your image and fix w&h params. [Documentation with examples here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339664/ckeditor-property-to-resize-a-image) And for example some code:

in HTML:

```
<pre>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
        {
             filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/uploader/upload.php'
        });
</pre>
```

in /uploader/upload.php :

```
<pre>
function resizeImage($file, $filename, $newwidth = 800, $newheight = 600)
{       
    $type = substr($file,strrpos($file,".")+1);

    switch($type) 
    {
        case 'jpg':
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            break;
        case 'jpeg':
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            break;
        case 'gif':
            $src = imagecreatefromgif($file);
            break;
        case 'png':
            $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
            break;
        default:
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            break;
    }

    list($width,$height)=getimagesize($file);
    $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

    switch($type) {
        case 'jpg':
            imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);
            break;
        case 'jpeg':
            imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);
            break;
        case 'gif':
            imagegif($tmp,$filename,100);
            break;
        case 'png':
            imagepng($tmp,$filename,9);
            break;
        case 'wbm':
            imagewbmp($tmp,$filename,100);
            break;
        default:
            imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);
            break;
    }
    imagedestroy($src);
    imagedestroy($tmp);
    return true;
}

$img = resizeImage($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name'], $newwidth = 800, $newheight = 600);
</pre>
```

p.s. there are tones of scripts for search query "php image resize" or etc.

**2.** Use some CKeditor mode. And here is solution: [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339664/ckeditor-property-to-resize-a-image).